# Clojure: What is wrong with my implementation of flatten?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I've been working through problems on [4Clojure](http://4clojure.com) today, and I ran into trouble on [Problem 28](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/28), implementing flatten.

There are a couple of definite problems with my code.

```
(fn [coll]
  ((fn flt [coll res]
    (if (empty? coll)
        res
        (if (seq? (first coll))
            (flt (into (first coll) (rest coll)) res)
            (flt (rest coll) (cons (first coll) res))))) coll (empty coll)))
```

I could use some pointers on how to think about a couple of problems.

1. How do I make sure I'm not changing the order of the resulting list? `cons` and `conj` both add elements wherever it is most efficient to add elements (at the beginning for lists, at the end for vectors, etc), so I don't see how I'm supposed to have any control over this when working with a generic sequence.
2. How do I handle nested sequences of different types? For instance, an input of `'(1 2 [3 4])` will will output `([3 4] 2 1)`, while an input of `[1 2 '(3 4)]` will output `(4 3 2 1)`
3. Am I even approaching this from the 'right' angle? Should I use a recursive inner function with an accumulator to do this, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: seq? does not check for datastructures that can be iterated over, it checks for actual sequences. You need to use sequential? for that instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try to use HOF (higher order functions) as much as possible: it communicates your intent more clearly and it spares you from introducing subtle low-level bugs.

```
(defn flatten [coll]
  (if (sequential? coll)
    (mapcat flatten coll)
    (list coll)))
```

Comment: I think I need more experience with the standard library, I didn't even know about `mapcat` or `sequential?` until your answer.

Comment: Maybe I am just not understanding how `mapcat` works, but I don't see where `coll` is being reduced with each recursive call to `flatten`. Obviously it works, but the terseness of this function hides the complexity. I am trying to install the `trace` utility (I wish this came standard in Clojure implementation) to try and understand this voodoo.

Comment: The function passed to mapcat takes 1 value and return a seq of values, it is called for each value of the original coll and then all seqs are concatenated.
So if coll is really a coll we flatten each element and concatenates teh results, if it's not a collection, we wrap it in a list, just to return a seq.

Comment: i'd trouble understand this until i realize the line with mapcat is apply the function to each element in the coll var

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your questions about lists and vectors. As you might see in tests, output is list. Just make correct abstraction. Fortunately, clojure already has one, called **sequence**.

All you need is **first**, **rest** and some recursive solution.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
(defn flatten [[f & r]]
  (if (nil? f)
    '()
    (if (sequential? f)
      (concat (flatten f) (flatten r))
      (cons f (flatten r)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it in a tail call optimised way, within a single iteration, and using the least amount of Clojure.core code as I could:

```
#(loop [s % o [] r % l 0]
   (cond
    (and (empty? s) (= 0 l))
    o
    (empty? s)
    (recur r
           o
           r
           (dec l))
    (sequential? (first s))
    (recur (first s)
           o
           (if (= 0 l)
             (rest s)
             r)
           (inc l))
    :else
    (recur (rest s)
           (conj o (first s))
           r
           l)))
```